# Sometimes when the function runs it works perfectly, other times it cannot access the properties of the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, geojson, gpx

```
const tj = require('@mapbox/togeojson');
const fs = require('fs');

const gpxToJson = async function (trailSlug) {
  // node doesn't have xml parsing or a dom. use xmldom
  DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

  fs.readdir(`./public/traildata/${trailSlug}/gpxFiles/`, (err, files) => {
    let newGpx;
    files.forEach(async (item, i) => {
      const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fs.readFile(
          `./public/traildata/${trailSlug}/gpxFiles/${item}`,
          'utf8',
          async function (err, data) {
            const gpx = await new DOMParser().parseFromString(data);
            const converted = await tj.gpx(gpx);
            console.log(typeof converted);
            converted.features[0].properties.name = item
              .replace('-', ' ')
              .split('.')[0];

            if (i === 0) {
              newGpx = converted;
            }

            if (i > 0) {
              newGpx.features.push(converted.features[0]);
            }

            if (i === files.length - 1) {
              //   console.log(newGpx);
              fs.writeFile(
                `./public/traildata/${trailSlug}/mastergeoJSON`,
                JSON.stringify(newGpx),
                'utf-8',
                (err) => {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  console.log('The file has been saved');
                }
              );
            }
            res(converted);
          }
        );
      });
      await promise;
    });
  });
};

gpxToJson('terra-cotta');
```

Hey there, I am trying to make a program that converts GPX files into one GeoJSON File. Everything seems to be going well so far except for every one in 5 times I run the code, I get a ***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined*** error from **"newGpx.features.push(converted.features[0])"**

I know the file is an object (as i have done the console.log(typeof converted) and it comes back as an object), I tried promisifying the entire forEach loop (but may have had an issue with the implementation).

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4E0T.png)

Does anyone have a resource that might steer me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `files` multiple files or only one file? Because if it is multiple, then you set `newGpx` only for the first element, since you only set it when `i === 0` and that is only true for the first element of `files`.

Comment: The Files variable is multiple files, The code essentially is to take the information from every file and push it to the features array on the first file. (Like combining all of the files into one JSON file)

Comment: As an aside - `await promise` does nothing useful in a `.forEach()` loop because `.forEach()` is not promise aware.  Put it in a regular `for` loop and then the `await` would do something.  This code can be rewritten in a massively simpler way using a regular `for` loop with `await` and using `fs.promises.readFile()` and `fs.promises.writeFile()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Got it working by getting rid of the .forEach(), thanks for your help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a much simpler version that uses a `for` loop which is promise-aware (a `.forEach()` loop is not promise-aware) and uses the built-in promise versions of `readdir()`, `readFile()` and `writeFile()` which, when combined with `await` makes the code a lot simpler.

```
const tj = require('@mapbox/togeojson');
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

const gpxToJson = async function (trailSlug) {
    const srcDir = `./public/traildata/${trailSlug}/gpxFiles/`;
    const files = await fsp.readdir(srcDir);

    let newGpx;
    for (let file of files) {
        const fullPath = path.join(srcDir, file);
        const fileData = await fsp.readFile(fullPath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        const gpx = new DOMParser().parseFromString(fileData);
        const converted = await tj.gpx(gpx);
        converted.features[0].properties.name = file.replace('-', ' ').split('.')[0];
        if (!newGpx) {
            newGpx = converted;
        } else {
            newGpx.features.push(converted.features[0]);
        }
    }
    await fsp.writeFile(`./public/traildata/${trailSlug}/mastergeoJSON`, JSON.stringify(newGPx), { encoding: 'utf8' });
};

gpxToJson('terra-cotta').catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: That is so much cleaner, I will implement using the fs.promises like you have shown. I'll also remember in the future that the .forEach() loop isn't promise-aware. Thanks a bunch for your help!!